# STL sort a vector by customer '<' operator. Why should I define the '<' operator as const?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, swap

I have defined a class "HasPtr":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class HasPtr {
public:
   HasPtr()
      : ps(new std::string()), i() {
      std::cout << "Default constructor execute" << std::endl;
   }
   HasPtr(const std::string &s, int a)
      : ps(new std::string(s)), i(a) {
      std::cout << "Sting with int constructor execute" << std::endl;
   }
   HasPtr(const std::string &s = std::string())
      : ps(new std::string(s)), i(std::stoi(s)) {
      std::cout << "String constructor execute" << std::endl;
   }
   HasPtr(const HasPtr &obj)
      : ps(new std::string(*obj.ps)), i(obj.i) {
      std::cout << "Copy constructor execute" << std::endl;
   }
   HasPtr & operator=(const HasPtr &rhs) {
      std::cout << "Assign execute" << std::endl;
      ps = new std::string(*rhs.ps);
      i = rhs.i;
      return *this;
   }
   ~HasPtr() {
      delete ps;
   }

   std::string get_str() const {
      return *ps;
   }

   int get_i() const {
      return i;
   }

   bool operator<(const HasPtr obj) const {
      std::cout << "Operator < execute" << std::endl;
      return i < obj.i;
   }

   friend void swap(HasPtr &lhs, HasPtr &rhs) {
      std::cout << "HasPtr::swap function execute" << std::endl;
      std::swap(lhs.ps, rhs.ps);
      std::swap(lhs.i, rhs.i);
   }

private:
   std::string *ps;
   int i;
};
```

This is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "HasPtr.h"

int main() {
   std::vector<HasPtr> v;
   v.push_back(std::to_string(10));
   v.push_back(std::to_string(5));
   v.push_back(std::to_string(7));
   v.push_back(std::to_string(3));
   v.push_back(std::to_string(2));
   v.push_back(std::to_string(9));

   std::cout << "==========List the elements==========" << std::endl;
   for (const auto &i : v) {
      std::cout << i.get_str() << " ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
   std::cout << "=====================================" << std::endl;

   sort(v.begin(), v.end());

   std::cout << "==========List the elements==========" << std::endl;
   for (const auto &i : v) {
      std::cout << i.get_str() << " ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
   std::cout << "=====================================" << std::endl;
}
```

1. I want to know why should I define the `bool operator<(const HasPtr obj) const` as const?
   I think all elements in the vector aren't const. Right?
2. I don't understand the execution:

```
String constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
String constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
String constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
String constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
String constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
String constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
==========List the elements==========
10 5 7 3 2 9
=====================================
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Operator < execute
Copy constructor execute
Operator < execute
Assign execute
Assign execute
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Operator < execute
Copy constructor execute
Operator < execute
Copy constructor execute
Operator < execute
Assign execute
Copy constructor execute
Operator < execute
Assign execute
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Operator < execute
Copy constructor execute
Operator < execute
Assign execute
Assign execute
Assign execute
Assign execute
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Operator < execute
Copy constructor execute
Operator < execute
Assign execute
Assign execute
Assign execute
Assign execute
Assign execute
Copy constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Operator < execute
Copy constructor execute
Operator < execute
Copy constructor execute
Operator < execute
Assign execute
Copy constructor execute
Operator < execute
Assign execute
==========List the elements==========
2 3 5 7 9 10
=====================================
```

Why there are so many "copy construction" and "assignment"?

3. Why the swap function has not been called? How the vector rearrange the elements?

I have been told that when the vector's element number is small, it uses a different algorithm but not swap.

The default constructor HasPtr() and the String constructor HasPtr(const std::string &s = std::string()) are not ambiguous. I don't know why.

Thanks

Comment: Did you realize that your third constructor `HasPtr(const std::string &s = std::string())` collides with your default constructor `HasPtr()`. I wonder that your compiler didn't complain... `g++` does: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b296fe4eed081769)

Comment: _Why the swap function has not been called?_ You provide an ascending test set. What do you think should be swapped? ;-)

Comment: The assignments may result from pivot-ing in `std::sort()`. I recommend to insert an output statement before `std::sort()` as well. I guess, a lot of copy constructions are from the `v.push_back(std::to_string(i));` and have nothing to do with sorting.

Comment: Thanks, Scheff. I will try it again and update the question further.

Comment: Hi Scheff, the default constructor and the string constructor are not ambiguous to my compiler. And after reshuffling the order, the result is more complicated.

Comment: _the default constructor and the string constructor are not ambiguous to my compiler._ Really, strange. Btw. The string constructor is ambiguous due to its default argument. (Actually, I would define the 2nd only. With the default argument it can act like a default constructor and is recognized as such.) What compiler are you using?

Comment: One reason for all the copy constructions is surely your `operator<()`. (Did you notice that every call of `operator<` is preceded by a copy construction?) The parameter is a value parameter but it should be const reference: `bool operator<(const HasPtr &obj) const`. (Please, note the little inserted `&` - one character, big impact.) ;-)

Comment: Hi Scheff, I use Visual Studio 2015. Its compiler is Visual C++ 14.0.
Detailed Info:
_MSC_VER : 1900
_MSC_FULL_VER : 190024215
_MSC_BUILD : 1
_MSVC_LANG : C++14

I get that the string constructor has a default parameter so that it can be used as a default constructor. I won't create two overlapped functions anymore.

Comment: Strange! I'm using VS2013. The sample from above link gives me very similar errors in VS2013.

Comment: I have tried it on Linux with g++. No error reported. Maybe this is a new rule?

Comment: Definitely not. [**Check on Compiler Explorer**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_rT9-o) (Beside of the fact, that VS2013 is not that new.) ;-)

Comment: If I create a HasPtr object using default constructor: HasPtr a; It will report the ambiguous error. If I create a HasPtr using string constructor: HasPtr a("test"); It won't report the error. So you are right. They are ambiguous. But it needs default construction to find it. Thanks, Scheff.

Comment: I made another example which is IMHO a bit more expressive: [**Life Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7219d59af22b1702). It seems that `std::sort()` doesn't depend on providing an overloaded `swap()`. Probably, `std::swap()` is applied in this case or `std::sort()` even doesn't use it. This might be the reason why you never see the concerning debug output.

Comment: Looking at the output, I'm now quite sure that assignment happens due to pivoting and re-assigning pivoted element. See here: `*this { str: "3", i: 3 } = test { str: "3", i: 3 }` (I guess, assign pivot to array again) and then `Test::~Test() { str: "3", i: 3 }` (Scope with pivot ends and pivot is destroyed).

Comment: @Scheff: It's valid to have overload sets in which some particular combination of default arguments are never used because there is a better match. This is just the most trivial case. This is legal because it's hard to define when exactly a particular default is redundant _for every possible overload resolution_. With templates involved, the size of the possible overload set cannot even be determined. (Halting problem).

Comment: @MSalters I read you comment but I'm not quite sure whether I understood it. Could you comment the test I did on [**Compiler Explorer**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_rT9-o)? At best, I could live with the comment of Zhen Yang that compiler doesn't complain when default construction is just not used...

Comment: @Scheff: **Declaring** an unusable overload is indeed not the error. That's why your error is on a concrete call, which means one specific overload resolution. My previous comment explained why the declaration is OK.

Comment: @Scheff I have tested several numbers and do you think it is a quicksort algorithm? It uses a temporary variable to exchange the elements rather than using swap.

Comment: If I remember right it is not pure quick-sort but combined with something else (but I might be wrong). Actually quick sort is the most common sorting algorithm (to me) which can achieve O(N log N) but the standard grants the complexity only but not the implementation. - Found it: [Wikipedia sort (C++)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(C%2B%2B))

Comment: Thanks, Scheff. You help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the `const` qualifier of `operator<()`:

Imagine you have this function

```
int
my_fnct(const HasPtr &a,
        const HasPtr &b)
{
  int result=12;
  // ... do something ...
  if(a<b) // <--- the comparison is important
  {
    result+=100; // or whatever ...
  }
  // ... do something ...
  return result;
}
```

If your `HasPtr::operator<()` was declared as

```
bool operator<(const HasPtr &obj) // <-- without const here
{ /* ... */ }
```

then the call `a<b` in the previous `my_fnct()` would
not be allowed by the compiler since the parameter `a` is
declared as `const` but the `operator<()` does not *promise*
in its prototype that `a` will not be modified..

On the other hand, if your `HasPtr::operator<()` is declared as

```
bool operator<(const HasPtr &obj) const // <-- const at the end here
{ /* ... */ }
```

then the call `a<b` in the previous `my_fnct()` will be allowed by
the compiler since the `const` keyword at the end of the prototype
ensures that the left operand of the comparison (`a` in my previous
example) will not be modified.

Answer (score 2):

Comparison operator should only compare, it is meaningless and harmful to compare and modify. Defining it const guarantees nothing bad will happen.

vector needs copy constructor copy assignment operators to be available. It will check for move constructor and move assignment operator too if the former wasn't available.